# jQuery .change() seems to only update once

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

A note before I start, I'm running jQuery in no conflict mode.
So, I have this code that is meant to uses a select element to choose out to sort a bunch of divs. The problem is, this:

```
jQuery('#fp-frag-select').change(function(){
```

Only wants to fire once. It could also be that this:

```
 var str = jQuery('#fp-frag-select').val();
```

Is only being updated once. I just need some direction on what I'm obviously doing wrong.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
     var $fpdivst = jQuery("div.fpboxt");


    jQuery('#fp-frag-select').change(function(){
      var str = jQuery('#fp-frag-select').val();
        if(str = 'htl'){
          var OrderedDivsAsc = $fpdivst.sort(function (a, b) {
            return jQuery(a).find('#alphat').text() - jQuery(b).find('#alphat').text();
        });
       jQuery("#fpcontainert").html(OrderedDivsAsc);
     }else if(str = 'lth'){
       var OrderedDivsAsc = $fpdivst.sort(function (a, b) {
         return  jQuery(b).find('#alphat').text() - jQuery(a).find('#alphat').text();
     });
    jQuery("#fpcontainert").html(OrderedDivsAsc);
    }else if (str = 'p'){
      var OrderedDivsAsc = $fpdivst.sort(function (a, b) {
        return jQuery(a).find('#alphat').text() - jQuery(b).find('#alphat').text();
    });
    jQuery("#fpcontainert").html(OrderedDivsAsc);
    }

      });

});
```

Comment: Note: `else if (str = 'p')` is assigning "p" to `str` (and in other areas of your code).

Comment: Pro tip: Inside of wordpress, use this shorthand, no-conflict-safe document ready `jQuery(function($) { ... $ is safe to use in here.... });`

Comment: Second pro tip: [yoda style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) comparisons would prevent the bug that @user7290573 is pointing out: `if ( 'p' = str) {` would throw an ERROR, rather than quietly assigning when it is meant to compare.  `if ('p' == str) {`.  Also, you should use `===` pretty much always in javascript, unless you are a javascript pro...

Comment: cale_b, you are gentleman and a scholar.